# How to declare 2D array in mongoose schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am doing in this way but got exception of syntax error.

```
alerts:  [{ name: String, time: Number},'default',[][]]
```

How can I declare this 2D array with default of empty array?

Comment: Empty would break the type bounds, since you just asked it to contain an object of "name" and "time" properties with their given types. What do you expect the data to look like anyway? I feel you might be confusing some terms here.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476239/mongoose-schema-workaround-for-multidimensional-array and see if this aplly to you r problem